# Cannot instantiate class issue in testng

Tags: java, selenium

I am facing an issue while running TestNG XML , it gives me an error that "Cannot instantiate class Tests.ZonesTestCases", would you please check the below XML and "zonetestcases" and test base which open the browser and path the URL

TestNG XML

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Idialogue Project">
    <test name="Login and Zone Test Cases">
        <parameter name="browserType" value="chrome" />
        <parameter name="appURL"
            value="https://41.206.136.84/IDialogueTest/login" />
        <classes>
            <class name="Tests.ZonesTestCases" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

ZoneTestCases.java

```
package Tests;

import java.io.IOException;


import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import Pages.HomePagePOM;
import Pages.LoginPOM;
import Pages.ZonePOM;
import Utilities.ExcelReader;

public class ZonesTestCases extends TestBase
{
    HomePagePOM HPPOM;
    ZonePOM ZonePOM;
    LoginPOM Login;

    
    public String ZoneUpdate = "";
    public String ZoneDelete = "";
    public String ZoneTypeEdit = "";
    public String ZoneExist="";


    private By ZoneUpdateBy = By.xpath("//tr/td[contains(text(), '"+ZoneUpdate+"')]/..//*[contains(text(), 'edit')]");
    public WebElement ZoneUpdatebtn = driver.findElement(ZoneUpdateBy);


    private By ZoneDeleteBy = By.xpath("//tr/td[contains(text(), '"+ZoneDelete+"')]/..//*[contains(text(), 'edit')]");
    public WebElement ZoneDeletebtn = driver.findElement(ZoneDeleteBy);


    private By ZoneTypeby = By.xpath("//span[contains(text(), '"+ZoneTypeEdit+"')]");
    public WebElement ZoneTypeList = driver.findElement(ZoneTypeby);


    private By ZoneExistby = By.xpath("//td[contains(text(), '"+ZoneExist+"')]");
    public WebElement ZoneExistlbl = driver.findElement(ZoneExistby);

    @DataProvider(name="Zone")
    public Object[][] userRegisterData() throws IOException
    { 
        ExcelReader ER = new ExcelReader();
        return ER.getExcelData();
    }

    @BeforeTest
    public void LoginFunZone() throws InterruptedException
    {
        Login = new LoginPOM(driver);
        Login.Login();      
    }
    
    @Test(dataProvider="Zone")
    public void AddNewZone(String ZoneName , String ZoneType , String Operation)
    {
        if (Operation =="Add")
        {
            HPPOM.ManageContent.click();
            HPPOM.Zones.click();
            ZonePOM.AddZonebtn.click();
            ZonePOM.ZoneNametxt.sendKeys(ZoneName);
            ZonePOM.ZoneTypeDDL.click();
            ZoneTypeEdit = ZoneType;
            ZoneTypeList.click();
            ZonePOM.Savebtn.click();
        }
    }
    //  @Test(dataProvider="Zone")
    //  public void EditZone(String ZoneName , String ZoneType , String Operation)
    //  {
    //      if(ZoneName !="Delete" && Operation != "Add" )
    //      {
    //          ZoneUpdate = ZoneName;
    //      }
    //      ZoneUpdatebtn.click();
    //      ZonePOM.ZoneNametxt.sendKeys(ZoneName);
    //      ZonePOM.ZoneTypeDDL.click();
    //      ZoneTypeEdit = ZoneType;
    //      ZoneTypeList.click();
    //      ZonePOM.Savebtn.click();
    //      
    //      ZoneExist = ZoneName;
    //      
    //      if(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//td[contains(text(), '"+ZoneExist+"')]")).size() != 0)
    //      {
    //          System.out.println("Zone is Edited Successfully");
    //      }
    //
    //      
    //
    //  }
    //
    //  @Test(dataProvider="Zone")
    //  public void DeleteZone(String ZoneName , String ZoneType , String Operation)
    //  {
    //      if(ZoneName =="Delete")
    //      {
    //          ZoneDelete = Operation;
    //      }
    //      ZoneDeletebtn.click();
    //      ZonePOM.Confirmbtn.click();
    //
    //      ZoneExist = ZoneName;
    //
    //      if(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//td[contains(text(), '"+ZoneExist+"')]")).size() == 0)
    //      {
    //          System.out.println("Zone is Deleted Successfully");
    //      }
    //  }
    //  
    @AfterTest
    public void LogoutFun() throws InterruptedException
    {
        //create three variables 1- UserName 2-Password 3-AgentName and make it readable from excel sheet
        Login = new LoginPOM(driver);
        Login.Logout();     
    }
}
```

TestBase.java

```
public class TestBase 
{
    public static WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeSuite
    @Parameters ({"browserType" , "appURL"})
    public void StartDriver(@Optional ("chrome") String BrowserType , @Optional ("https://41.206.136.84/IDialogueTest/login") String URL)
    {
        switch (BrowserType) 
        {
        case "chrome":
            System.out.println("Launching Chrome browser..");
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/Adds/chromedriver.exe");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            break;
        case "firefox":
            System.out.println("Launching Firefox browser..");
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            break;
        }
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.navigate().to(URL);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
```

i dont know how to solve this issue any suggestions

Error

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.2
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Cannot instantiate class Tests.ZonesTestCases
    at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:30)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance1(ClassHelper.java:423)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance(ClassHelper.java:336)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getDefaultInstance(ClassImpl.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getInstances(ClassImpl.java:190)
    at org.testng.TestClass.getInstances(TestClass.java:95)
    at org.testng.TestClass.initTestClassesAndInstances(TestClass.java:81)
    at org.testng.TestClass.init(TestClass.java:73)
    at org.testng.TestClass.<init>(TestClass.java:38)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.initMethods(TestRunner.java:389)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:271)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:241)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:192)
    at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_12$1.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG6_12.java:33)
    at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_12$DelegatingTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG6_12.java:66)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$ProxyTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:713)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:260)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.<init>(SuiteRunner.java:198)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1295)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1273)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1128)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:24)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Tests.ZonesTestCases.<init>(ZonesTestCases.java:31)
    ... 30 more
```

Comment: Can you share the full error and stacktrace please?

Comment: Done i shared the full error from IDE

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time, this is based upon IDE configuration. Please check for browser-specific project configuration settings. The reason for the error is basically TesntNG xml file is not able to find Tests.ZonesTestCases class